# Edit link not visible in Quick Launch after site provisioning using custom web template

Tags: web-template, onet, edit-links

I am using a custom web template to create a site based on team site template, but it is not showing the edit links on quick launch and top navigation.

This is the element of the web template:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <WebTemplate BaseConfigurationID="1"
             BaseTemplateID="0"
             BaseTemplateName="STS"
             Description=""
             DisplayCategory="ZK Sites"
             Name="CollabWebTemplate"
             Title="ZK collab site">
  </WebTemplate>
</Elements>
```

Anyone can tell me why I don't see the Edit Links?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `ProductVersion="15"` to tell SP you want the 2013 version? This is just a wild guess

Comment: I added it but did not help.